# How I can find maximum number in verilog array

Tags: verilog

So, I have a `reg[7:0] corr_Output[0:63];` which is filled with values in my module. How I can find maximum number in this array at one CLK cycle?
I wrote a 8 bit comparator:

```
module Comparator2D(
input [7:0] X1,
input [7:0] indexX1,
input [7:0] X2,
input [7:0] indexX2,
output [7:0] Y,
output [7:0] indexY
);

always begin
    if (X1 > X2) begin
        Y = X1;
        indexY = indexX1;
    end
    else begin
        Y = X2;
        indexY = indexX2;
    end
end
endmodule
```

But I dont know how I should  instantiate this module in my top design? I think I should use "for loop", or even write another module which will concatenate my Comparator2D module in pyramid form, but as I found  I cant pass whole array to input port of module, so Im a little stuck..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find minimum in array of numbers using Verilog for Priority Queue implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785351/find-minimum-in-array-of-numbers-using-verilog-for-priority-queue-implementation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using for/generate, like in this code sample, in which I can compare 8 bytes at a time.

The key point is that I cannot pass a memory as input (an array of registers), but I can pass an array of bits that hold the current values from memory.

```
// This is just your compare module.
module C2D (
    input wire [7:0] X1,
    input wire [7:0] indexX1,
    input wire [7:0] X2,
    input wire [7:0] indexX2,
    output reg [7:0] Y,
    output reg [7:0] indexY
    );

    always @* begin
        if (X1 > X2) begin
            Y = X1;
            indexY = indexX1;
        end
        else begin
            Y = X2;
            indexY = indexX2;
        end
    end
endmodule

// Compare 8 bytes at a time
module greatest8bytes (
    input wire [63:0] array,   // 8 byte array
    output wire [7:0] indexG,
    output wire [7:0] valueG
    );

    wire [7:0] value_l1[0:3];
    wire [7:0] index_l1[0:3];

    genvar i;
    generate
    for (i=0;i<8;i=i+2) begin :gen_comps_l1
        C2D cl1 (array[i*8+7:i*8],
                 i,
                 array[(i+1)*8+7:(i+1)*8],
                 (i+1),
                 value_l1[i/2],
                 index_l1[i/2]
                );
    end
    endgenerate

    wire [7:0] value_l2[0:1];
    wire [7:0] index_l2[0:1];

    generate
    for (i=0;i<4;i=i+2) begin :gen_comps_l2
        C2D cl2 (value_l1[i],
                 index_l1[i],
                 value_l1[i+1],
                 index_l1[i+1],
                 value_l2[i/2],
                 index_l2[i/2]
                );
    end
    endgenerate

    wire [7:0] value_l3[0:0];
    wire [7:0] index_l3[0:0];

    generate
    for (i=0;i<2;i=i+2) begin :gen_comps_l3
        C2D cl3 (value_l2[i],
                 index_l2[i],
                 value_l2[i+1],
                 index_l2[i+1],
                 value_l3[i/2],
                 index_l3[i/2]
                );
    end
    endgenerate

    assign indexG = index_l3[0];
    assign valueG = value_l3[0];
endmodule
```

The `greatest8bytes` module is synthesized the way you expect: as a pyramid-like arrangement of comparators:

[image: Circuit synthesized for greatest8bytes]
To connect an array of regs (a memory) to the input of this module, create a wire of the desired number of bits (64 in this example) and concatenate all elements of memory, like in this example module:

```
module findgreatest (
    input wire clk,
    input wire [2:0] addr,
    input wire [7:0] data,
    input wire we,

    output wire [2:0] indexG,
    output wire [7:0] valueG
    );

    reg [7:0] memory[0:7];  // 8 bytes
    // To load data from the outside so the synthesizer won't throw away memory
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (we)
            memory[addr] <= data;
    end

    wire [63:0] array = {memory[7],memory[6],memory[5],memory[4],
                         memory[3],memory[2],memory[1],memory[0]};
    greatest8bytes compar (array, indexG, valueG);
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is synthesizable, but it is good to know that SystemVerilog has built in min and max functions:

```
module maximum ();
reg[7:0] corr_Output[0:63] = '{0:8'd112, 2:8'd250, 3:8'd37, 4:8'd15, default:8'd25};
reg[7:0]  max_i[$];
reg[7:0]  min_i[$];

initial begin
    max_i = corr_Output.max;
    min_i = corr_Output.min;
    $display ("max=%d, min=%d", max_i[0], min_i[0]);
end
endmodule
```

Output:

```
# max=250, min= 15
```

**Alternatively**, it is probably shorter to just use this classic and synthesizable for-loop of comparisons:

```
always_comb begin
  max = corr_Output[0];
  for (c = 0; c <= 63; c++)
  begin
    if (corr_Output[c] > max)
    begin
       max  = array[c];
       index = c;
    end
  end
```